# Change function on Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, textfield, onchange

I have a textfield, and I want the field to be disabled or read only if I change text on the field. But, before that, I can't make change function. I don't know why.

I have tried this code :

```
$("#submitOrder_cust_id_name").click(function () {
    alert("Test");
});
```

and when I click the field it is working.

But, when I use this code

```
$("#submitOrder_cust_id_name").change(function () {alert("Test");});
```

or this code

```
$("#submitOrder_cust_id_name").on('change', function () {
    alert("Test");
})
```

it doesn't work at all.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add a fiddle? so that it will be easy to take quick solution.

Comment: without a proper HTML, it is hard to comprehend what exactly is happening.

Comment: Chaitanya : pardon me, what do you mean about fiddle?

Comment: Krishna Prashatt :
`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.submitOrder.cust_id_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control m-input only_text m-input--air", @style = "width:100%; height:35px;", @maxlength = "30" } })`

Comment: That's Razor, not HTML - check the rendered html in the browser.

Comment: "it doesn't work at all" is not very helpful. There's nothing wrong with the change even code you have (as shown by a provided "answer").  Can elaborate/debug what's wrong with the `.on("change"..` code?

Answer (score 0):

jquery **change** event trigger only when hit enter on the text box. If you want to trigger a event when you enter any character use "keypress" instead of "change"

Refer this : 
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_keypress.asp

Comment: This is work, Sir. But, it's not what i want. Because, it will execute function on first typing. and my purpose is when the cursor move to another field, then the last filed will be disable.

actually i want to be like this

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_change_ref

but it doesn't work

Comment: Then try onfocusout event  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onfocusout

Answer (score 0):

use on `'change'`:

```js
$('#submitOrder_cust_id_name').on('change', function () {
  alert('test');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="submitOrder_cust_id_name" />
```

Comment: And yes, it's work too. But, it's not what i want. Because, it will execute function on first typing and every single input. and my purpose is when the cursor move to another field, then the last filed will be disable.

actually i want to be like this

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_change_ref

but it doesn't work

Comment: Then you can use `'change'`. I have edited my answer

Comment: Which is now exactly the same as OPs code - so can't be a valid answer.  We need to establish *why* this code doesn't work for OP.

Comment: Yeah ... well I have just proven to him that this works with a fiddle, so let's wait for his comment and then I will edit again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.blur()`. This will be called when the input field loses focus:

```js
$('#submitOrder_cust_id_name').on('blur', function () {
  alert('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="submitOrder_cust_id_name" />
```